# What will be the output of the following unix code?

Tags: linux, unix

```
a=x b=x
 If [ $a -eq $b ]
 Then
 echo "a is equal to b"
 else
 echo "a is not equal to b"
fi
```

Will the above code successfully output "a is equal to b" or there is some error?

Comment: I guess it would be easier for you to try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking at your script, you use the single bracket version of the `test` command. This is in contrast to the double-bracket version which is a shell-internal test.

The `test` command states:

> **`INTEGER1 -eq INTEGER2` :** `INTEGER1` is equal to `INTEGER2`

But you are not comparing integers, but strings (unless `x` could be a dummy name for something that could be an integer.). Hence, the `test` will fail.

```
$ [ x -eq x ]
[: integer expression expected: x
```

So your output will read `a is not equal to b`.

If you want to compare strings, then it is advised to use the operator **`=`**:

> **`STRING1 = STRING2` :** the strings are equal

Answer (score 0):

`-eq` is for integer comparisons, but you are comparing strings. Use `=` (or `bash`-ism `==`):

```
[ "$a" = "$b" ]
```

Like i did, quote variable expansions to prevent word splitting and pathname expansion.